# PHP - How get random element in array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$AllNums = array();
//array is { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "1" };

$RandNums = array_rand($AllNums, 1);
// var_dump($RandNums) show - int(0)

$Rand = $AllNums[$RandNums[0]];
```

but `echo 'Rand = '.$Rand` print on display `Rand =`.

Tell me please why we can not get `$Rand`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_rand($AllNums, 1);` returns a value, not an array, so you don't have to add `[0]` in `$Rand = $AllNums[$RandNums[0]];`

```
$AllNums = range(1, 2);

$RandNums = array_rand($AllNums, 1);

$Rand = $AllNums[$RandNums];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.shuffle.php):

```
$AllNums = array();
shuffle($AllNUms)
$Rand = $AllNums[0];
```

Comment: This is my preferred method

Comment: Always important to mention that it will completely change the array though.

Answer (score 1):

You are using it wrong. Should be:

```
$AllNums = array('1', '2');
$RandNums = array_rand($AllNums, 1); // this return an int() which can be used as an index
$Rand = $AllNums[$RandNums]; // no need to put `[0]`
echo $Rand;
// Actually no need to explicitly put 1, since its default it 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) of `array_rand` specifies that if you are getting only one value with `array_rand`, it returns a single value. It only returns an array if you are trying to get more values (using the second parameter)

Answer (score 0):

echo $AllNums[array_rand($AllNums)];

use array_rand()
http://php.net/array_rand

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`mt_rand`**

```
$RandNums = mt_rand(0, count($AllNums) - 1);
$Rand = $AllSeets[$RandNums];
```